# Adding Shadow Effects to Group of Shapes with VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, shapes, vba

I have discovered a rather strange issue when applying a shadow effect to a group of shapes in Excel with VBA.

Say I got two shapes, like in the picture below, a square and a triangle next to each other which I have grouped into the group named **MyGroup**. What I now want to do is to apply a drop shadow effect to this group of shapes. By hand I can do this by selecting the group and then adapting my desired shadow settings.

[image]

Now, ultimatly I would want to do this routine as part of a VBA code project that I am working on. Hence, I am trying to apply the exact same effect to the group of shapes by VBA. The code that I can come up with for this task is

```
Sub AddShadowToGroup()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("MyGroup").Shadow
        .Type = msoShadow21
        .RotateWithShape = msoFalse
    End With
End Sub
```

The end result of running this code is that it applies the shadow effect to each seperate shape in the group, which has the unfortunate side effect that it looks like this.
[image]

Also note in this second picture that no shadow effect has been set for the selected group.

I.e. with respect to VBA the above code is equivalent to formatting each shape like this

```
Sub AddShadowToGroup()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("Triangle").Shadow
        .Type = msoShadow21
        .RotateWithShape = msoFalse
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("Square").Shadow
        .Type = msoShadow21
        .RotateWithShape = msoFalse
    End With
End Sub
```

In this simple example a solution could be to move the square to the front, relative to the triangle. This way the shadow from the triangle will be hidden beind the square in an almost acceptable fashion. However, in the project I am working on I need a much more complex structure of multiple shapes, and in that case the idea of strategically ordering the different shapes doesn't quite cut it.

I can't seem to come up with a way to get VBA to format a **group** of shapes instead of each sperate shape in the group. Does anyone know how this can be done? Also, this issue is not limited to applying a shadow effect. The issue is the same when applying any effect to a group of shapes.

Comment: does ´group.duplicate ´ create one shape or 2 in your example. Can't test it now. I'm on phone.

Comment: Duplication the group generates the same two shapes again.

Comment: Think this might be a known bug. That said, having had a play, oddly it seems to work if you comment out the `rotatewithshape` line.

Answer (score 0):

The .RotateWithShape should have read msoFalse, not mosFalse, hence the reason it worked when commented out.